# What is the meaning of the expression A('pk') in Django Tables 2?

Tags: django, django-models, django-tables2

I'm trying to setup a `LinkColumn` and I've seen in the examples that a the `args` parameter has usually the form `args=[A('pk')]`. I'm wondering what is the meaning of the `A()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/api-reference.html#django_tables2.utils.Accessor) of django-tables, A is the Accessor Class.

A string describing a path from one object to another via attribute/index accesses. For convenience, the class has an alias A to allow for more concise code.

Relations are separated by a . character.

So basically you are using the primary key in this example to access the objects.

Answer (score 1):

From django-tables2 [source code](https://github.com/jieter/django-tables2/blob/master/django_tables2/utils.py#L286)

```
class Accessor(str):
    '''
    A string describing a path from one object to another via attribute/index
    accesses. For convenience, the class has an alias `.A` to allow for more concise code.
    Relations are separated by a ``.`` character.
    '''
```